# Using derived type for member variables in derived classes

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

Is there as best practices way to deal with a member variable in a derived class being the type it was declared in the parent class?

For example, here are simplified Manufacturer and Car classes:

```
Public Class Manufacturer
    Protected _name As String
    Protected _country As String
End Class

Public Class Car
    Protected _manufacturer As Manufacturer

    Sub New(manufacturer)
        _manufacturer = manufacturer
    End Sub

End Class
```

If I implement the following derived classes:

```
Public Class Honda
    Inherits Manufacturer

    Sub New()
        _name = "Honda"
        _country = "Japan"
    End Sub

    Public Property Prefecture As String

End Class

Public Class Accord
    Inherits Car

    Sub New(manufacturer)

        MyBase.New(manufacturer)

        ' This doesn't work
        _manufacturer.Prefecture = "Tokyo"

    End Sub

End Class
```

The only way I know of to work around this issue is to cast `_manufacturer` to `Honda`:

```
    Dim myManufacturer As Honda = manufacturer
    myManufacturer.Prefecture = "Tokyo"
```

Another approach I have considered is to create a wrapper for the `_manufacturer` object:

```
Sub New(manufacturer As Honda)

    MyBase.New(manufacturer)

    MyManufacturer.Prefecture = "Tokyo"

End Sub

Private ReadOnly Property MyManufacturer() As Honda
    Get
        Return _manufacturer
    End Get
End Property
```

This is a little easier to work with.

These are extra steps I am hoping I can avoid. Thanks for any pointers you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to make `Car` a generic class.

```
Public Class Car(Of T As Manufacturer)
    Protected _manufacturer As T

    Sub New(manufacturer As T)
        _manufacturer = manufacturer
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can then declare `Accord` as a class derived from `Car` where the generic manufacturer type is `Honda`

```
Public Class Accord
    Inherits Car(Of Honda)

    Sub New(manufacturer As Honda)
        MyBase.New(manufacturer)

        ' This should work
        _manufacturer.Prefecture = "Tokyo"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would probably involve Generics. If the Car class has multiple subobjects, you just add more types in the declaration? `(Of M As Manufacturer, E As Engine, P As Paint, ...)` ?

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Yes, you can add multiple types as you describe.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a shot!

Comment: I can make this into a new question but will mention it here in case: what if `Manufacturer` has events that you want to handle in `Car`?

Comment: Figured it out as I was typing up new question: class constraint